# Confidence Interval for factor loadings of 2PL model

Tags: confidence-interval, psychometrics, profile-likelihood, mirt

I estimated a 2PL model obtained for some dichotomous data presenting answers of 12 "yes/no" questions from about 200 individuals. Now I want to calculate the confidence intervals for the factor loadings of all items. I used the `mirt` package to estimate my model which also offers profile-likelihood CI's (PLCI) for both parameters of model. I calculated the PLCI's and also estimated bootstrapped standard errors for the model using the fisher-z-transformation to standardize them to the boundaries of the corresponding factor loadings (-1,1). Then calculated the Wald-statistic for the factor loading of each item (Code below). Still, I receive values for the upper and lower bound of the CI that exceed the boundaries of the factor loadings, which makes no sense to me.

Code for Confidence interval from Wald-statistic

```r
boot.fun <- function(mod){
  so <- mirt::summary(mod, verbose=FALSE)
  as.vector(so$rotF) %>%
    # standardize std error for factor loadings using 
    # fisher z transformation
    {log((1+.) / (1-.)) / 2}
}

confInt_2PL <- function(IRT_model, conf_level = .05){

  #find Z critical value
  crit <- qnorm(p=conf_level/2, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  r <- mirt::summary(IRT, verbose=FALSE)$rotF %>% as.vector()
  
  booted.loads <- mirt:::boot.mirt(IRT, boot.fun=boot.fun, 
                           technical = list(NCYCLES = 100000),
                                   parallel = 'snow', 
                           ncpus = parallel::detectCores())
  std_error <- map_dbl(.x = 1:12,~booted.loads$t[,.x] %>%
                         na.exclude() %>%
                         as.vector() %>%
                         var() %>%
                         sqrt())
        
  conf_upper <- r+crit*std_error
  
  conf_lower <- r-crit*std_error
        
  conf_int_2PL <- tibble(names = IRT@Data$tabdata %>% colnames(),
                         loadings = r,
                         conf_lower = conf_lower,
                         conf_upper = conf_upper)
  
  return(conf_int_2PL)
}
```

**Q: How can I calculate correct confidence intervals for the factor loadings of a 2PL model estimated with the `mirt` package?**

Comment: Use percentile based CI?

Comment: @JeremyMiles Good idea! Another colleague gave me the same hint. So what I did to achieve this is transforming the upper/lower bound in the following sense:

$$(e^{2*\text{conf}_{(upper/lower)}}-1)/(e^{2*\text{conf}_{(upper/lower)}}+1)$$

Comment: So that the we get percentile based CI with adjusted bounds corresponding to the bounds of the factor loadings of the 2PL model.

Comment: @mugdi why are you using the bootstrap to obtain CI instead of supplemental EM (SEM) or the Oakes method? Both require next to no additional computational time, and the mirt packages coef function provides CI based on these methods.

Comment: @PrestonBotter With only 200 observations I would not trust an analytical solution. Might be wrong with such a low sample size.